# Batch file to rename all files in a folder by adding current date/time to beginning of filename

Tags: date, time, batch-file, rename

I can't seem to understand how batch files add yyyy/mo/dd/hh/mm/ss to the beginning of filenames. (Using Windows 7) Accuracy to the second is important.

It doesn't actually have to be a batch file, it just has to be a small program which can be executed by Directory Monitor whenever I add files to a folder: http://brutaldev.com/page/Directory-Monitor.aspx
I only imagine that a batch file would be the simplest and most efficient approach, but any other suggestions are welcome.

I work with many sequentially numbered files with overlapping filenames and I need a quick way to rename them whenever I add them to a folder such that there will never be any file with the same name yet they will still remain in sequential order. This is how I thought of adding the current date and time to the beginning of the filename and why seconds are important, since I can easily add multiple sets to a folder in under a minute but certainly not under a second. It would be ideal if the batch file could ignore file extensions and simply add the current date/time to the beginning of any file added to the folder.

Comment: `I can't seem to understand how batch files add yyyy/mo/dd/hh/mm/ss to the beginning of filenames.` but you don't have any batch files??? Probably you mean *you don't know how to write a batch file to do that*

Answer (score 1):

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%" & set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"

:: this line will rename the files in the current folder which haven't already
:: been renamed by checking for the fullstamp format at the start of the line
:: but it will skip this batch file

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d ^|findstr /v "^[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*_[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*" ') do if /i not "%%a"=="%~nx0" ren "%%a" "%fullstamp% - %%a"

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   @ECHO off
   SETLOCAL
   IF [%1] NEQ [] goto s_start

   :: Author - Simon Sheppard, July 2003
   :: Tested for Windows NT, 2K, XP 

   ECHO STAMPME.cmd
   ECHO REName a file with the DATE/Time
   ECHO.
   ECHO SYNTAX
   ECHO       STAMPME TestFile.txt
   ECHO.
   ECHO       STAMPME "Test File.txt"
   ECHO.
   ECHO       STAMPME "c:\docs\Test File.txt"
   ECHO.
   ECHO       In a batch file use CALL STAMPME ...

   :: To change the filename format just change around the last line below

   GOTO :eof

   :s_start

    SET _file=%~n1%
    SET _pathname=%~f1%
    SET _ext=%~x1%

    ::Get the date
   ::  note ISO 8601 date format would require 4 digit YYYY Year)

   FOR /f "tokens=6-8 delims=/ " %%G IN ('NET TIME \\%computername%') DO (
         SET _mm=%%G
         SET _dd=%%H
         SET _yy=%%I
     )

   :: Get the time
   FOR /f "tokens=2-4 delims=:." %%G IN ('cmd /c "time<nul"') DO (
         SET _hr=%%G
         SET _min=%%H
     SET _sec=%%I
     GOTO :done
   )
:done
   ECHO Today is Year: [%_yy%] Month: [%_mm%] Day: [%_dd%]
   ECHO The time is:   [%_hr%]:[%_min%]:[%_sec%]

   REN "%_pathname%" "%_hr%-%_min%-%_sec%@%_file%%_ext%"
```

This seems to work for me

Comment: Also as a small possibility to get wrong date/time as they are get at different times: just before midnight, you can get 23:59 and read next day following. Batch isn't much fast.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer solutions, that are not dependent to local settings (wmic gives always the same format):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (a.*) do (
  for /f %%i in ( 'wmic os get localdatetime /value ^|find "Local"' ) do set %%i
    set ldt=!LocalDateTime:~0,4!-!LocalDateTime:~4,2!-!LocalDateTime:~6,2!-!LocalDateTime:~8,2!-!LocalDateTime:~10,2!-!LocalDateTime:~12,2!-!LocalDateTime:~15,3!

    echo seconds        ### ren %%a !LocalDateTime:~0,14!%%a
    echo milliseconds   ### ren %%a !LocalDateTime:~0,18!%%a
    echo with separator ### ren %%a !ldt!-%%a
)
```